# How does ComboBox extend beyond the window borders?

Tags: combobox, javafx

I noticed that the ComboBox can extend beyond the window borders. I'd like to implement something like that for a custom control of mine, but can't figure out how to do it. Can someone give me a hint how to do this or at least where I could start looking?

Here is a [link to a screenshot](http://i60.tinypic.com/28lghgy.png), since I cannot yet post images on Stackoverflow

Thanks in advance

Edit: Ok, I got the answer at the Orcale forums, here's a link to the [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3511058).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer at the Oracle forums, here's a link to the [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3511058).

Basically you just need to wrap the control in a popup window and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through

```
cmbBox.setVisibleRowCount(100);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that, the above screenshot is from my own program. What I would like to do is create my own control that can grow larger than the window borders.

Comment: @user3257919. Then your question is incomplete. We cannot know the spec and properties of your custom control, from what components does it consist etc. infos, since you didn't provide them. Update your question with more specific details and may post the sample code.